# SQL server many to one mirroring

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-mirroring

I have two SQL servers, server A and server B running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard.  Can I setup a third server that will be a mirror for both server A and server B?  I can't seem to find any documentation stating that a many-to-one mirroring is allowed or possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Mirroring occurs at the database level. A single SQL server instance can receive mirrors from as many other SQL servers as you want.